# Unable to send canvas div to front

Tags: html, css

Question is very simple becuase there is sample markup which is showing a problem.

How can i make `input type="file"` clickable in following example? I tried to work with `z-index` but it seems to do nothing here.

```
<html>
    <div style="z-index: 0">
        <img src="#" width="350" style="position: absolute;" />
        <canvas width="350" style="border: thick; position: absolute"></canvas>
    </div>

    <div style="z-index: 10">
        <input type="file" />
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to add `position` to your `div`s. `z-index` will not work without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `position` with z-index, or it will not work.

```
// HTML
<div class="canvas">
    <img src="#" width="350" />
    <canvas width="350"></canvas>
</div>

<div class="file">
    <input type="file" />
</div>

// CSS
.canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.file {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;  
    z-index: 10;
}
```

http://codepen.io/paulcredmond/pen/yakkkY